# Model derivative API returns no data for hierarchy or properties

Tags: autodesk-model-derivative

When retrieving data from model derivative API it returns status success, but no data. This happens intermittently; running the query on the same model will eventually return the data - sometimes first try, other times after several tries. It is set to SVF 3D. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue with those endpoints, we have logged that and our development team is aware of it. As a workaround, at the moment, you will need to implement a retry policy in your code, sorry for the bad news.

Also to ease the large payload returned by the /properties endpoint when the model contain a lot of components we have implemented a new endpoint which lets you specify the dbId to return properties for. It should be available on the public API in the near future.

Hope that helps.

Comment: any news on this? I am experiencing the same problem as OP, with ` :urn/metadata/:guid/properties?objectId=:objectId` I always need to try multiple times before getting anything else than just "success"

Comment: I'm not working at adsk anymore, so little chance I can help you in the near future. You would need to try your luck with support one more time. Cheers!